# how git shallow works in a dev level

Tags: git, libgit2

I have a file system with backup history that I would like to convert in a git repository.

I would like to do this in phases. The first phase is to create a shallow repo with only the head files. And then I would like to unshallow it step by step. The goal is to have a valid git repo to start working with asap.

Could you please give me some references from where I should start reading first - to determine is this possible, and second - how.

Answer (score 2):

Let's move away from "shallow" and "deepen" as terms here, as these mean different things from what you're describing. They are used in relation to fetching history from a repository, not creating new history before the existing one.

What you're asking about is creating history before the one you have. This violates the causality constraints which git's history recording relies upon (and any other version control system, for that matter). History moves forward, and putting new content *before* the existing one goes against what these systems are meant to do, which is accurately record changes.

Git provides a few tools to "rewrite" history. With `git rebase`'s  `--onto` and `--root` options, you can transplant a full history on top of a different one. What this does, however, is not make the history longer, but apply changes from a series of commits/patches on top of a  different one. When looked from certain angles, it can look equivalent, but it's different history. In order to work with it, you need to make the other systems/people working with the history forget about the old one.

If you're sure you want to use Git for this, I'd suggest looking at the manual page for `git rebase` and maybe `git update-index` and `git commit-tree` to see how to work with the scripting level of git, but you should think about why you want Git. This isn't made for backups, but for software development. You would still have to reinvent the whole backup part of the system.

Comment: I already have the file system backup as a legacy - no need to reinvent anything there. thanks